# php mysql photo upload by email, just like flickr

Tags: php, email, file-upload, imap, flickr

I need to develop a system where a user can sign into our site and have their own unique uploading email address (how to create email ids on a shared hosting with php automatically?). They can then use that address to send their pictures from their mobile phone and have it uploaded to the site. The website Flickr.com has this functionality, below are the instructions that they give their users:

Go to http://www.flickr.com/account/uploadbyemail/ on your desktop and sign into Flickr. You will receive a unique Flickr email uploading address.

1. Create a new email message on your phone and attach the photo you want to upload. Use the photo title in the subject line and photo description in the body.
2. Send the email to your Flickr email uploading address. Your photo will be posted to your to your Flickr account, with title and description displayed.

Any ideas on how to do this? Please help! 
Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have tried using the imap functions to parse emails. I have a gmail account and tried the following code:

```
$authhost="{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}";
$user="email@gmail.com";
$pass="password";

$mbox=imap_open( $authhost, $user, $pass );
$check = imap_check($mbox);
print 'Total messages: '.$check->Nmsgs;
```

But the problem is this code returns a number which is less that actual number of messages in my inbox. How to solve this? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Either pipe the email to a script rather then a mailbox/dir on your server, or search mailboxes & parse mails with the `imap` plugin.